# Angular: Two way binding between Directive and Controller does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a Slider as an Angular directive. The Problem is, that I need the value of the Slider in my Controller, so I can send it via Json to a Service. The value is used in the Directive to update the length of a corresponding span and should get updated whenever the Slider is moved the value should be updated in the Directive and in the Controller. Right now it just updates the variable to the value I set in the Controller once and then it just stays as it is.

Controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('SliderController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.m = 5;
    $scope.m2 = 45;
}]);
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.directive('slider', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
           value: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.header = attrs.header;
            scope.unit = attrs.unit;
            scope.min = attrs.min;
            scope.max = attrs.max;
            scope.step = attrs.step;
            // scope.value = attrs.value;



            // scope.model = attrs.ngModel;

            var calculation = function () {
                // console.log(scope.value);
                return scope.value / scope.max * 100;
            };

            scope.onChange = function () {
                if( isNaN(scope.value) || parseInt(scope.value) > parseInt(scope.max)) {
                    scope.value = scope.max;
                }
                scope.width = calculation();
            };             
        },
        templateUrl: '../html/slider.html'
    };
});
```

HTML Template

```
<div class="slider">
<h3>{{header}}</h3>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="span-back">
        <span style="width:{{width}}%"></span>
    </div>
    <input class="input-range" type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" step="{{step}}" data-ng-model="model" data-ng-change="onChange()" >
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-value" ng-model="model" data-ng-change="onChange()">
        <div class="input-base">{{unit}}</div>
    </div>
```

Index HTML

```
<div ng-controller="SliderController">
    <slider id="floating-div" header="My Slider" min="1" max="250" step="1" unit="testunit" data-ng-model="m2" value="m2"></slider>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you need to $observe the changes, imo.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not seem to work. I just get the name of the variable ("m2") and not the value of the variable passed in my Directive.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the directive's controller, you should declare it as such. And use the [bindToController](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) too.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('slider', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    controller: SliderController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: {
      value: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    ....
```

See if that works.

Also, don't forget to import the slidercontroller.

```
import SliderController from './slider.controller.js';
```

(or whatever your path/name is)

Or if import is not available, write the controller directly into the same file as the directive. So the same as above, without the import, but add in the controller:

```
function SliderController($scope) {
 ... etc
}
```

Then the controller: SliderController; line in the directive should work.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, I got an error in the console now, saying "SliderController is not defined" do I have to give it in the directive or something?

Comment: my IDE does not recognise the "as", is there another way to import it properly?

Comment: Edited it, replace as with from.

Comment: I was just informed that we use ecmascript 5, so I can not use imports